# What is the fastest route to regenerate Types in a Program instance after *some* files modified?

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

I have a `Program` instance in which I've modified a few nodes in a few `SourceFile`. I'd like to regenerate the types for the modified `SourceFile`s in the most performant way possible. (Note: I am *not* emitting)

The initial way I've done this is:

- Create a `CompilerHost` and hook `getSourceFile` to allow it to serve modified `SourceFile` if available
- Run a transformer on all `SourceFile`, update modified collection from result
- Recreate `Program` using the same compilerHost (serves updated files)

I'm trying to determine if there is a more optimal way to do this.

I've investigated the possibility of using a LanguageService, but it appears that `ts.createLanguageService` simply triggers a re-creation of `Program` when files are changed.

Another route I've looked at is `ts.createWatchProgram`. It seems to use similar logic in implementing an `isProgramUptoDate()` function which runs `createProgram` if filenames have changed. For my purposes, it's looking like both would add unnecessary complexity and presumably drag over my original route.

However, because I don't have much experience with either yet, it's possible that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After taking the day to do some heavy perf testing and digging I've learned a few things.

It seems the best results can be gained through caching unchanged `SourceFile` and hooking `CompilerHost` to return from cache, when available. (I was recently told that the `LanguageService` works in a similar way)

If you're only modifying a few files, this can have a tremendous boost in performance. When I modified none of the 230 TS files, `Program` reloaded in `1ms` consistently without supplying `oldProgram` and `100ms` when supplying it.

However, even with many files modified, gains can be still be realized.

The big take-away, for me, is that each *new* `SourceFile` which gets served from the `CompilerHost` will have to have its types walked again, which can get expensive.

So the ways to improve speed are the following:

1. Create a `CompilerHost` and hook `getSourceFile()` to serve the `SourceFile` from a cache map, when available.
2. If you can get away with not using the `TypeChecker` during `ts.transform()`, don't create a `Program` instance until after you transform. (use your compilerHost to load the `SourceFile[]` for use with `ts.transform()`)
3. During transform, keep track of which files actually get modified and only update those files in your cache.

Example code:

```
import * as ts from 'typescript';
import * as glob from 'glob';
import {
  CompilerHost, CompilerOptions, HeritageClause, IndexedAccessTypeNode, SourceFile, SyntaxKind, TypeReferenceNode
} from 'typescript';


/* ********************************************************* *
 * Helpers
 * ********************************************************* */

export const nodeIsKind = <T extends ts.Node = never>(node: ts.Node, ...kind: ts.SyntaxKind[]): node is T =>
  kind.some(k => node.kind === k);


/* ********************************************************* *
 * Compiler
 * ********************************************************* */

function createHookedCompilerHost(hostFiles: Map<string, SourceFile>, compilerOptions: CompilerOptions) {
  const host = ts.createCompilerHost(compilerOptions);
  const originalGetSourceFile = host.getSourceFile as Function;

  return Object.assign(host, {
    getSourceFile(fileName: string, languageVersion: ts.ScriptTarget) {
      return hostFiles.get(fileName) || originalGetSourceFile(...arguments);
    }
  });
}

function transformNodes(program: ts.Program) {
  const srcFiles = program.getSourceFiles() as SourceFile[];
  const updatedFiles = new Set<string>();

  const transformer = (context: ts.TransformationContext) => {
    function visit(fileName: string) {
      return (node: ts.Node): ts.Node => {
        /* Ignore these */
        if (nodeIsKind<HeritageClause>(node, SyntaxKind.HeritageClause)) return node;

        /* Wrap in tuple */
        if (nodeIsKind<TypeReferenceNode>(node, SyntaxKind.TypeReference) || nodeIsKind<IndexedAccessTypeNode>(node, SyntaxKind.IndexedAccessType)) {
          updatedFiles.add(fileName); // Mark file as modified
          return ts.createTupleTypeNode([ node ]);
        }

        return ts.visitEachChild(node, visit(fileName), context);
      }
    }

    return (sourceFile: ts.SourceFile) => ts.visitNode(sourceFile, visit(sourceFile.fileName));
  };

  const { transformed } = ts.transform(srcFiles, [ transformer ], program.getCompilerOptions());
  return transformed.filter(sourceFile => updatedFiles.has(sourceFile.fileName));
}


/* ********************************************************* *
 * Config
 * ********************************************************* */

const fileNames = glob.sync('./test/assets/**/*.ts');

const compilerOptions = {
  noEmit: true,
  target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES5,
  module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
  strictNullChecks: false,
};


/* ********************************************************* *
 * Main
 * ********************************************************* */

/* Setup Host & Program */
const hostFiles = new Map<string, SourceFile>();
const host = createHookedCompilerHost(hostFiles, compilerOptions);

/* Load SourceFiles */
const sourceFiles = fileNames.map(fileName => host.getSourceFile(fileName, compilerOptions.target));

/* Build Program */
let program = ts.createProgram(fileNames, compilerOptions, host);

/* Pre-cache sourceFiles */
program.getSourceFiles().forEach(srcFile => hostFiles.set(srcFile.fileName, srcFile));

/* Transform files & update affected SourceFiles */
const transformed = transformNodes(program);
for (const sourceFile of transformed)
  hostFiles.set(
    sourceFile.fileName,
    ts.createSourceFile(sourceFile.fileName, ts.createPrinter().printFile(sourceFile), sourceFile.languageVersion)
  );

/* Re-generate Program */
program = ts.createProgram(fileNames, compilerOptions, host);

/* Do what you need with the TypeChecker here */
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you have questions or need help.